# Finite State Machine validity

Tags: code-golf, string

I've been around for a while, watching you golf and I really enjoy it.
I came up with a challenge for you all so let's begin!

## Challenge

*I assume that everyone knows what Finite State Machine (FSM) is, I will edit the the description if needed.*

- Your program will take only one input consisting in a string that represents a FSM.
- The first character of the input is the FSM's initial state and the last character is the FSM's final state.
- Transitions are represented as two consecutive characters (`AB` will be the transition from state A to state B. `ABCD` will be the two transitions `A to B` and `C to D`)
- In this challenge, the FSM is considered valid when you have at least one path from the initial state to the final state.

## Goal

Output a truthy value, telling the world if the input is a valid FSM (any equivalent for `True` of `False` is fine)

#### Bonus

- **-20%** if you add all the sequences of valid paths to the output

## Examples

`AB` should output (with bonus) `true AB`

`ABC` should output `false` (No transition to state C)

`ABCEBD` should output (with bonus) `true ABD` (The presence of unreachable states C and E doesn't make it false)

`ISSTSFTF` should output (with bonus) `true ISF ISTF`

`ABACBCCD` should output (with bonus) `true ACD ABCD`

`ABACBCD` should output `false`

`ABACADCDBCDEBE` should output (with bonus) `true ABE ADE ACDE ABCDE`

## Final word

If you think this challenge lacks something, please tell me, I'd really like to see the answers you can come up with

Comment: You should probably clarify that the transition pairs are not overlapping. So `ABCD` represents only two transitions `A->B` and `C->D` and *not* `B->C`. Otherwise the challenge would be trivial.

Comment: It would also be a good to have a truthy test case where some state other than the final state is not reachable.

Comment: Never assume that we know. :P I know I don't know what a Finite State Machine is.

Comment: This is not that related to finite state machines. It's just reachability in a directed graph.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! With respect to bonusses, check out [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8102/11259).  4 votes is certainly not to be taken as consensus, but IMO your bonuses - especially the first one - add little to the challenge

Comment: Darn.. I looked in Peter Taylor's graph theory challenge index for a dupe target, but the entry under reachability was 'too many to mention'.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think this is supposed to illustrate an answer with only the second bonus

Comment: @feersum, pretty much everything in [tag:path-finding] is close to a dupe, but I can't find such a minimalistic reachability question before, so I will hold off on the supervote.

Comment: Thank you. I'll edit the post to take @MartinBüttner 's advices in account.
If you think this is a dupe, I'm sorry but since I haven't found a challenge close to what I had in mind, I posted this one.

Comment: Which characters are valid names for states?

Comment: @feersum I would say that [A-Z] are valid names to keep it simple.

Comment: The third test case is wrong as: `In this challenge, the FSM is considered valid when you have at least one path from the initial state to the final state.`  or is there something I do not understand?

Comment: @MegaTom You're totally right. I edit that right away

Comment: You should also include a test case that doesn't start with `A`.

Comment: @user81655 It doesn't matter as I said `The first character of the input is the FSM's initial state and the last character is the FSM's final state.`

Comment: Test cases are meant for testing if a program follows the specs or not. Hardcoding `A` as the initial state would save 6 bytes in my solution, but technically make it invalid even though it passes all the test cases. The only way anyone would know is by studying the code.

Comment: In that case, I'll add one.

Comment: I think this is a dupe. While I think a pure canonical is-there-a-path question would distinguish itself from the many other, this one is yet another challenge to extract the graph from a somewhat inconveninent input format and then do pathfinding. While I have to choose a single question when specifying a dupe, there's many reachability questions that cover similar ground

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

```js
s=>(a=[...s]).map(_=>a.map((m,i)=>p=i%2&r[s[i-1]]?r[m]=1:r[m]),r={},r[s[0]]=1)&&p
```

### Explanation

Takes the states as a string and returns a `1` for true or `undefined` for false. This method was the shortest I could find, but it means that it's impossible to include the bonus because it just determines reachability, not the paths.

```js
s=>
  (a=[...s])        // a = states as an array
  .map(_=>          // loop a number of times to ensure all states have been reached
    a.map((m,i)=>   // for each state m at index i
      p=            // p = the reachability of the final state
        i%2         // if this is the last state of a pair
        &r[s[i-1]]? // and the first state is reachable
          r[m]=1    // set the last state and p to reachable
          :r[m]     // else set p to the reachability of the state
    ),
    r={},           // map of truthy values for reachable states
    r[s[0]]=1       // set the initial state to reachable
  )
  &&p               // return the final result
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>(a=[...s]).map(_=>a.map((m,i)=>p=i%2&r[s[i-1]]?r[m]=1:r[m]),r={},r[s[0]]=1)&&p
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="ABACADCDBCDEBE" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice one! I like the explanation. :)

Comment: @Askirkela Thanks. Nice first challenge, by the way! I enjoyed making this.